# Twitter4Jを使用したUserStreamの実装について

Tags: android

[Twitterクライアントを作ってみよう](http://qiita.com/gabu/items/53857fcfa871b921af45)

このサイトをを参考にTwitter4Jを用いてTwitterクライアント作成の勉強をしていました。
この方法ではすぐにAPI制限に引っかかってしまうのでUserStreamでタイムラインを取得したいのですがどのようにすればいいのか全くわからず教えていただきたいです。
また、ListActivityについて検索してもあまり出て来ずListViewとListActivityの違いもあまりよくわからないので、二つの違いも教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Answer (score 2):

Twitter4JでUserStreamを利用するコードのサンプルを書いてみました。参考になれば幸いです。

UserSreamについての詳細はこちらをご覧ください。
http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterStream.html

app/build.grade

```
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.4'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-async:4.0.4'
compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-stream:4.0.4'
```

MainActivity

```
String consumerKey = "ここに";
String consumerSecret = "あなたの";
String accessToken = "キーを";
String accessTokenSecret = "入力";

// config
Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
    .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret)
    .build();

StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
  @Override
  public void onStatus(Status status) {
    // tweet取得でログを表示する
    Log.i("UserName: "+status.getUser().getName(),"Tweet: "+status.getText());
  }

  @Override
  public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice statusDeletionNotice) {}

  @Override
  public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int numberOfLimitedStatuses) {}

  @Override
  public void onScrubGeo(long userId, long upToStatusId) {}

  @Override
  public void onStallWarning(StallWarning warning) {}

  @Override
  public void onException(Exception ex) {}
};

TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(conf).getInstance();
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.user();
```

サンプルプロジェクトの全体はGitHubに公開しておきました。
https://github.com/xsota/Twitter4jUserStreamTest

ListView,ListActivityについては以下を参照してください。
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html?hl=ja
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html?hl=ja