# Twitter4Jを使用したListActivityへのツイートの追加について

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

[Twitter4Jを使用したUserStreamの実装について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31337/twitter4j%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%9Fuserstream%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)

こちらの質問で教えていただいたものを使いUserStreamで取得したツイートをLogに表示することはできたのですがツイートをListに追加する方法が分かりません。
今までは以前の質問と同じく[Twitterクライアントを作ってみよう](http://qiita.com/gabu/items/53857fcfa871b921af45)
の方法でやっていたのですがこれだとUserStreamで取得しているのにもかかわらずAPIが切れてしまい困っています。どのようにすればツイートを取得しそれをリアルタイムでListActivityのListに追加することができるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

UserStream で得られたツイートを ListView に表示するサンプルを作ってみました。

ストリームを表示する Activity のレイアウトに ListView を追加します。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  tools:context="com.xsota.twitter4juserstreamtest.MainActivity">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

そして StatusListener の中で Handler を利用して ListView に更新を反映させます。

```
  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

StatusListener listener = new StatusListener(){
      @Override
      public void onStatus(final Status status) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            adapter.add("UserName: "+status.getUser().getName() + " Tweet: "+status.getText());
          }
        });
      }
```

サンプルのソースコードをを公開しましたので参考にしてください。

https://github.com/numa08/Twitter4jUserStreamTest